# Where do I get the ResourceGroup for AzureResourceManager CmdLets?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

The new and soon to supercede AzureRsourceManager cmdlets all  require a `-ResourceGroupName` parameter. Where am I expected to get this? Not including the UI, since that'd mostly defeat the purpose of automating.

Currently, I'm calling `Get-AzureResourceGroup` and trying each one until I get a hit. This is extremely slow - on the order of minutes. For example, to get WebApp information, I'm running this,

```
$groups = Get-AzureResourceGroup
foreach ($g in $groups)
{
    if ($ResourceGroup) { $ResourceGroup.Value = $g.ResourceGroupName }
    $app = Get-AzureWebApp -Name $Name -ResourceGroupName $g.ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Verbose "Checking $($g.ResourceGroupName)"
    if ($app)
    {
        $ResourceGroups[$g.ResourceGroupName] = @($ResourceGroups[$g.ResourceGroupName]) + $Name
        return $app
    }
}
```

Comment: Get-AzureRmResource will give you a list of all of the resources in your subscription - though your question isn't very clear on what it is you are trying to achieve. what is your end goal...

Comment: @MichaelB I'm trying to retrieve Azure WebApp information. In the "old" versions of the cmdlets you only needed to provide a `Name` and possibly a `Slot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @theadriangreen noted in his comment, it's faster to directly query the REST API. I found that some of the RM cmdlets actually do this anyway.

I've written a set of PowerShell functions to make using the API easier and faster (uses caching), in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/makhdumi/021b56faab5d6796fbb2).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the portal and navigate to your web app you can easily see which resource group it's in. See the screenshot below. What resource group is, is an arbitrary name to group resources. For example below you can see that it is grouping two Web Apps and two App Service Plans.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but going through the UI defeats the purpose of scripting. I've clarified my question since.

Comment: Your solution is the best only using cmdlets. If you want a faster solution, then you can try directly querying the Azure REST API. For instance, a GET on the following URL is to list all of the sites for a given subscription:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION-ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2015-08-01

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Get-AzureRmResourceGroup** PowerShell command from Azure PowerShell without any parameter to get all the resource groups in very fast response time.

Reference Link: [Get-AzureRMResourceGroup description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603831.aspx)

Note: You need to update your Azure PowerShell to the latest version for this new feature. The current version is **1.0.1 (November 2015 Update)**